# Debugging a CRD host

Tags: python, debugging, kubernetes, localhost, tls1.2

I’m new to debugging and I have a task to debug an issue.

I know I have to create a CRD host and TLS context CRD with a host name but I’m not sure how to do so. Can someone show me how?

Here is the bug:

[Diagnostic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY2eJ.jpg)

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to do, can you elaborate a little bit more? Looks like you are using Ambassador with a CRD but no clue what you are trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: I have to create a host CRD with a host name. I also have to a TLS context CRD with the same host name.